# Jquery validation string length replacing field characters beforehand

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, formvalidation-plugin

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

I am using an input mask on my phone number fields and I would also like to include them in my validation using Jquery validation plugin but the masking I am using on the fields for readability has characters in it I would like to replace before the validation is done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TxtMobile").focusout(function () {
            var mobile = $("#TxtMobile").val();
            $("#TxtMobile").rules("add",
            {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 10,
                minlength: 10,
                regex: mobile.replace(/\ /g, '').replace(/\_/g, '')
            });
        });
}
```

Some examples of what the format for the numbers can come out like at the moment are:

```
04__ ___ ___
0422 226 999
____ ___ ___
```

So ideally I'd like to work this into the validation somehow

```
mobile.replace(/\ /g, '').replace(/\_/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this

```
$("#TxtMobile").rules("add", {
   required: true,
   maxlength: 10,
   minlength: 10,
   regex:mobile.replace(/\ /g, '').replace(/\_/g, '')
   });
```

Comment: I've updated my sample with what I am using and it is not working?

Comment: Use this code 
$("#secret").keyup(function() {
        var val = this.value;
        var newVal = '';
        while (val.length > 4) {
          newVal += val.substr(0, 4) + '-';
          val = val.substr(4);
        }
        newVal += val;
        this.value = newVal;
    });

Above code for when user type it will automatically convert into your format number

Comment: include also $.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function (phone_number, element) {
  
        
            return (/(\d{0,4})-(\d{0,4})-(\d{0,4})/).test(phone_number);
        }, "Invalid phone number");


 $("form").validate({
rules: {
  secret: "phoneUS"
  }

});